# Print in screen without interruptions assembly 8086

Tags: video, assembly, buffer, interruption

I have a big problem with a program in assembly x86. I have to print in screen, that's easy, the real problem is that I have to do it without interruptions. I know that I have to write directly in video buffer, also I know that this memory is located in 0B800h, but I haven't found anything else. Can you give me a hand with this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy screen data to buffer then do what you need

```
mov ax,0b800h
mov es,ax
mov  di,0
mov si,0
lea ax,buffer
mov ds,ax
cld
mov cx,80*25*2
rep movsb
buffer db 80*25*2 dup(0)
```